# How do i precompile the stdc++.h in mac os

Tags: c++, macos, compilation

I am a competitive programmer who uses the gcc(HOMEBREW) to compile the c++ files
since the stdc++.h has a long list of all the other header files so i wanted to know how do i precompile the bits/stdc++ file.

Comment: Note: Precompiled headers improved build time, something that's not normally a concern in competitive programming. [Here's what GCC has to say on using pre compiled headers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html)

Comment: Unless you have  large project, another thing  not commonly found in competitive programming, you won't get much of a build-time boost from precompiled headers. Never tried it with a single-file project myself, so for all I know it'll slow you down.  For a small project, you usually just use the minimal headers required for the job.

Comment: @user4581301 okk i somehow managed to do so

Comment: @SiddhantSarkar how did you do it ? can you brief ?